# AVAssetExporter crashing on setting videoComposition

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition

I'm using AVFoundation to crop and rotate a video, but I'm getting a SIGABRT error when setting the AVAssetExporter's videoComposition property.

```
assetExport.videoComposition = videoComposition;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: Full stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the video composition on your `AVPlayer`'s `playerItem` as well?  Temporarily setting your `playerItem.videoComposition` to nil should prevent the crash.  AVFoundation doesn't seem to like sharing the same composition between two different objects.  I know this is an old question, but I've spent 2 days debugging this, hope it will help someone out in the future.